# How do you find the type parameters of an ancestor class?

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection

How do you find the type arguments of an inherited class?

To illustrate, given these definitions:

```
// Scala 2.11.1
class DerivedClass extends Function1[Int, String] {
  def apply(i: Int): String = "Zep"
}

def printTypeInfo(typ: Type) {
  println(typ.typeSymbol)
  println(s"  typeArgs=${typ.typeArgs}")
  typ match {
    case TypeRef(prefix, symbol, args) =>
      println(s"  TypeRef($prefix, $symbol, $args")
    case _ =>
      println(s"  no match")
  }
  println
}
```

printing the type parameters of a leaf-node class:

```
  printTypeInfo(weakTypeOf[DerivedClass])
  printTypeInfo(weakTypeOf[Function1[Int, String]])
```

works fine, producing this output:

```
class DerivedClass
  typeArgs=List()
  TypeRef(A.type, class DerivedClass, List()

trait Function1
  typeArgs=List(Int, String)
  TypeRef(scala.type, trait Function1, List(Int, String)
```

But the same approach applied to `.baseClasses`:

```
weakTypeOf[DerivedClass].baseClasses.foreach(sym =>
  printTypeInfo(sym.typeSignatureIn(weakTypeOf[DerivedClass])))
```

loses the type parameters:

```
class DerivedClass
  typeArgs=List()
  no match

trait Function1
  typeArgs=List()
  no match

class Object
  typeArgs=List()
  no match

class Any
  typeArgs=List()
  no match
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val TypeRef(_, _, List(from, to)) = 
  typeOf[DerivedClass].baseType(typeOf[Function1[_,_]].typeSymbol)
```

Result:

```
from: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.Int
to: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! I never would have thought of `Function1[_, _]`. I generalized it for any function by searching the type symbols in `definitions.FunctionClass.seq`.